# Qt - can't find proper sender()

Tags: c++, qt

I want to determine which button was clicked, but in my **for loop** that I use to find the right **QPushButton** it cannot be found. Pointers to these **QPushButtons** are placed in vector of vectors.

That is how I connect buttons with a function that I want to use when button is used

```
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<size; ++j)
        {
            grid->addWidget(board->dis_board[i][j], i, j);
            board->dis_board[i][j]->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
            connect(board->dis_board[i][j], SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(move()));
        }
    }
}
```

And here you have mentioned function

```
void Game::move()
{
    unsigned long x=0;
    unsigned long y=0;
    QPushButton* buttonSender = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    for(; x<board->dis_board.size(); ++x)
    {
        for(; y<board->dis_board.size(); ++y)
        {
            if(board->dis_board[x][y] == buttonSender)
                break;
        }
    }
    board->move(x,y);
}
```

where **move(x,y)** is a method of an object called board

The problem is the things that when I go through the **for loop** in **Game::move()** my **x** and **y** get value **5** (so I assume that **sender()** can't be found).

What might be the problem? If more code is needed I can deliver more of it.

There are no errors shown

Comment: Please provide a more complete example code.

Comment: Do you have available Qt 5's non-macro signals and slots?

Comment: The thing is that your `break;` statement exits the inner `for` loop only, however it still continue to iterate through the outer `for` loop till the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` statement only exits the inner `y`-loop, but not the outer `x`-loop.

The following code should work for you:

```
void Game::move()
{
    QPushButton* buttonSender = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
    for(unsigned long x=0; x<board->dis_board.size(); ++x)
    {
        for(unsigned long y=0; y<board->dis_board.size(); ++y)
        {
            if(board->dis_board[x][y] == buttonSender)
            {
                board->move(x,y);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot that I able to do that as I do have less than 15 reputation points. Done

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you have Qt 5 and a C++11 or later compiler, you can just include the original `x` and `y` with the connection.

```
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j<size; ++j)
    {
        grid->addWidget(board->dis_board[i][j], i, j);
        board->dis_board[i][j]->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        connect(board->dis_board[i][j], &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this, i, j](){ board->move(i, j); });
    }
}

// No Game::move
```

Comment: Will try that too. Thanks